# How to rename file name in Linux using the command "rename"?

Tags: linux, rename, filenames

I have some files that names like this:

```
2311110-1_1.umi_bc1.fastp.fq.gz
2311110-1_1.umi.fastp.fq.gz
```

Now i want to change the names to:

```
231110-1_1.umi_bc1.fastp.fq.gz
231110-1_1.umi.fastp.fq.gz
```

After searching in google, i try to use the command "rename":

```
rename 's/2311110/231110/' 2311110*
```

However, after i do this, it doesn't work. The file name doesn't change.
So is there any error with the command? By the way, there are so much files that is's impossible change the name using "mv".

Comment: There are two different `rename` commands. Which one do you run?

Comment: "However, after i do this, it doesn't work." Can you post what are the error message you got? May be add verbose mode with `-v`.

Comment: `for f in 2311110*; do mv "$f" 231110"${f#2311110}"; done`

Comment: @Mathieu There is no error message. I mean after running this command, nothing happens.

Comment: `rename  -n 's/^231111/23111/' 231111*` will tell you what it *would* do without the `-n`

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash, you can use variable substitution:

```bash
for i in 2311110*
do
    # just remove the echo when you tested that proposed mv command seems good
    echo mv "$i" "${i/2311110/231110}"
done
```

See [devhints.io/bash](https://devhints.io/bash) to learn more about variable manipulation.

Comment: This command is unsafe if the filenames contain whitespace. To fix it, add `"` around `$var`s.

Comment: The Bash-only [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) limts the usefulness of this answer; it would not be hard to turn it into a POSIX-compatible one. In fact I posted a portable solution in the comments a bit before this answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Linux, with the `rename` package installed (`sudo apt-get install rename`), your *rename* command works for me:

```
$ touch 2311110-1_1.umi_bc1.fastp.fq.gz 2311110-1_1.umi.fastp.fq.gz
$ ls 23111*.gz
2311110-1_1.umi.fastp.fq.gz  2311110-1_1.umi_bc1.fastp.fq.gz
$ rename 's/2311110/231110/' 2311110*
$ ls 23111*.gz
231110-1_1.umi.fastp.fq.gz  231110-1_1.umi_bc1.fastp.fq.gz
```

If it doesn't work for you, then use `rename -v ...`, and check the error message it prints.

FYI It's possible to do automated renames likes this without the `rename` command (see comments and other answers), with the advantage of working on systems where `rename` is not installed. Most Linux systems don't have `rename` installed by default.